# Centering a TextField wrapped in Flexible in a Row widget that resides in a Column widget in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to center Two elements in a Row widget that resides in a Colum widget. The last Row in this code is of interest. I have noticed that when I remove the "Flexible(...)" widget from that Row, then the Text centers horizontally. Otherwise, both elements stick to the left-hand side of the screen. I want both of the elements to stick to the center. I tried wrapping the Flexible widget into a Container and then Aligning that container to the middle, Flutter did not like that.

**I am looking for the *Two widgets* in the *last row* to center horizontally**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Example 1"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: ButtonBar(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Button"),
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Button"),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: ButtonBar(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Button"),
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Button"),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Email:"),
                Flexible(
                    child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: "Enter Email",
                  ),)),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Text("clock"),
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Row Widget` will try to use as much space as possible (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)
if you wrap your children widgets inside a Flex and centre the Main Axis, you will see the children elements centred

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child: Text("Email:"),
    ),
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child: TextField(
        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: "Enter Email",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually moved the piece towards the center, although not perfectly centered, it's good enough.